# Auto-detect time of day

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa

I'm writing a daily to do list app, and want the app to update certain elements with each new day. This isn't a problem if the user closes the app one day and then reopens it the next -- I just compare days in the startup methods.

However, this is a problem if the user happens to be using the app exactly at midnight. At midnight, daily task elements need to reset themselves automatically for the new day.

Here's my issue -- I could have a constant thread running in the background, always accessing [NSDate date] and checking for a new day. But I feel like there must be a better way, especially because this only has to happen once per day (and then, only if the user is using the app at midnight).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` and `applicationWillEnterForeground:`, setup an `NSTimer` scheduled to trigger at midnight. Also, register for `UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification` to reschedule the timer for time zone changes etc.